# One page website, how to close navigation after click the link?

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, navigation

This is the structure

```
<nav class="menu-opener">
    <div class="menu-opener-inner"></div>
</nav>
<nav class="menu">
    <ul class="menu-inner">
      <a href="#about" class="menu-link"><li>About</li></a>
      <a href="#menu" class="menu-link"><li>Menu</li></a>
      <a href="#order" class="menu-link"><li>order</li></a>
      <a href="#direction" class="menu-link"><li>Direction</li></a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The script I'm using

```
$(".menu-opener").click(function(){
$(".menu-opener, .menu-opener-inner, .menu").toggleClass("active");
   });   
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Let me know if you have an idea for adding line on the script. I am still new with java script.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to remove the `"active"` class, which is presumably how the menu is opened.

```
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".menu-opener, .menu-opener-inner, .menu").removeClass("active");
});
```